# Crossfading back and forth two ImageViews using 2 functions

Tags: android, imageview, android-animation

I'm trying to crossfade two ImageViews by invoking a method when the first image is clicked, then we fade into the second image(alpha set to 0 initially), then I would like to fade back into the first image after clicking on the second image.
It works when crossfading from one image to the other using only one method, but if when I add the other method to crossfade back to the previous image, nothing happens when I click on the image.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public void narutoFade(View view){
        ImageView naruto =(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.naruto);

        ImageView narutosage =(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.narutosage);


        naruto.animate().alpha(0f).setDuration(2000);
        narutosage.animate().alpha(1f).setDuration(2000);
    }

    public void narutoSageFade(View view) {

        ImageView naruto2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.naruto);
        ImageView narutosage2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.narutosage);

        narutosage2.animate().alpha(0f).setDuration(2000);
        naruto2.animate().alpha(1f).setDuration(2000);

   }
}
```

Comment: use `TransitionDrawable`, docs say: `An extension of LayerDrawables that is intended to cross-fade between the first and second layer. To start the transition, call startTransition(int). To display just the first layer, call resetTransition().`

Comment: That is another method to do it, but I need more details. Thanks a lot though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you should think about declaring both as Fields, declare them only once in onCreate()/onResume(), and write one crossfade method that serves both :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ImageView naruto, narutosage;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       ...
       naruto =(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.naruto);
       narutosage =(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.narutosage);

    }

    public void crossfade(View fadeIn, View fadeOut) {
        fadeIn.animate().alpha(1).setDuration(2000);
        fadeOut.animate().alpha(0).setDuration(2000);
    }

}
```

and in your Button onClicks you just call :

```
crossfade(naruto, narutosage);
```

or

```
crossfade(narutosage, naruto);
```

Comment: I finally found a way to do it my way. But thanks for your answer! It's another way to do it and at least you tried to explain how it works :)